# Presenting View Controller from a block doesn't animate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am using `SVPullToRefresh`

```
__weak InventorySearch *safeSelf = self;

[self.tableView addPullToRefreshWithActionHandler:^{
    [safeSelf refresh];   
 }];
```

The method refresh does some setup work then calls `[self presentmodalviewcontroller:controller animated:YES];`

However the view doesn't animate and is simply presented immediatley.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
 [safeSelf refresh];
```

try this

```
[safeSelf performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(refresh) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Comment: Perfect! As a bonus can you provide an explanation?

Comment: UI is handled on main thread by iOS. SO any logic that is being implemented on some background thread does not work as expected. So all UI related statement must be implemented on main thread. Other business logic should be implemented on background thread, like loading data from DB, calling a web service etc